# Make my plot denser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, core-plot

I'm using Core-Plot on my iPhone app.
I need all the records data to be viewed without moving the plot space (the user interaction with the graph is set to NO).
The problem is that the values on my X axis are spread beyond the visible view, and can only be seen when moving the graph.

How can I make the values closer on my X axis?

10x

Comment: Are you asking how to adjust the range of the Y axis so that all data points are visible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the `xRange` of your plot space. Similar to `NSRange`, plot ranges are given as a starting location and length, which can be negative. Look at the Core Plot sample programs for numerous examples.